# I cant find my sqlite database created for Windows phone 8.1 phonegap app in Visual studio community 2013?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, web-sql

I am creating a Windows phone 8.1 phonegap app. It is using local database called websql using this link. I created app and datas can be fetch from offline. It is working very well.

But the problem is I need to see the database I created. Where to find the database. In Visual studio there is no option to see the database.

There is no editor.

Where is it stored?

Comment: please help me to find this

Comment: Hello...Couldnot find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I searched my hard disk and found the sqlite database to be created in the following location.

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages\io.cordova.hellocordova_54dbk1tt7zbhy\LocalState

Not sure if this is the standard location for windows 8.1 applications packaged using cordova. But I believe you can find it by searching your hard disk for the database name.

Hope it helps.